# How to loop this so I can add more twitter accounts

Tags: python, loops, twitter

```
import time
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
import requests
from requests_oauthlib import OAuth1
from urlparse import parse_qs

# application's key and key secret
ck = ''
cs = ''

# obtain request token
oauth = OAuth1(ck, cs)
r = requests.post(url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token', auth=oauth)
credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
request_key = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
request_secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

#obtain authorization from twitter user
print('Visit this link to authorize the TweetBot:\n https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=%s' % request_key)
verifier = raw_input('Enter your verification code: ')

# obtain access token
oauth = OAuth1(ck, cs, request_key, request_secret, verifier=verifier)
r = requests.get(url='https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token', auth=oauth)
credentials = parse_qs(r.content)
tk = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
ts = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]

# access TwitterAPI with the obtained access
api = TwitterAPI(ck, cs, tk, ts)
f = open('tweetbot.txt', 'rU')
for line in f:
    r = api.request('statuses/update', {'status' : line})
    print line,
    print r.status_code
    time.sleep(600)
```

I have this code but I want it to add multiple twitter accounts. I guess I'd need to loop the input and store them in different variables? Please give me the best solution. I'm not that advanced with python.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Why not a while loop?

Comment: I tried it but I can't get it to store in different variables

Comment: Ok, will post an answer later.

Answer (score 0):

Alright @user3392493, what you need is a while loop, but with several if statements inside and a counter variable, so the variables are set based on what number the counter is at:

```
enoughaccounts = False
counter = 0
while not enoughaccounts:
    counter += 1
    if counter == 1:
        # Do Everything
        account1 = .....
    if counter == 2:
        # Do Everything
        account2 = .....       
    if counter == 3:
        # Do Everything
        account3 = .....
    if counter == 4:
        # Do Everything
        account4 = .....
    moreaccounts = input('Add another account? (type yes or no)')
    if moreaccounts == 'no' or moreaccounts == 'No' or moreaccounts == 'NO':
        enoughaccounts = True
```

This should do what you want it to, if you need anything else just ask :)

Comment: just checked back, thank you for your time to help, ill try this and tell you how it goes

Comment: ive come across so many more errors, i guess ill just move onto something else, i understand most of this but some of it i just cant get my head around. theres already things like this around anyways but thanks for taking your time to help, really appreciated